# Generate dynamic page with magento 1.9. - 2.1

Tags: magento2, programmatically, page, code-generation

I have a php api to generate html code. What I'd like is to use it with magento.

is posible to do it ?

This is my target :

run_magento() --> generate magento page

By example in magento 2.1 we have by default :

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

And this code will generate a magento page using magento block structure.

What I'd like to get is we could to generate those block structures dinamically.

To you understand me :

```
Instead to have : <p><?php echo $content ?></p>
I'd like to have : echo <?php generate_tag(p, $content) ?>
```

This same idea using magento Api. I have this idea already implemmented with Drupal 5-8 without problems and now I'd like to try to implemment with Magento.

Is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Raj KB<magepsycho@gmail.com>
 * @website http://www.magepsycho.com
 */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require '/path/to/magento2/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Add Magento Code or non-magento code here...
```

This script can be used for quick testing your Magento2 functionality also.

Comment: Is a good starting point.